# How to include coupon code in newsletter/subscription email in Magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.6, magento-1.7

I have created a shopping cart rule 'fixed amount discount for whole cart' and I want to include the coupon code in the subscription/newsletter email to the customer. Any suggestions?

I could find the option to create transactional email template and add sing custom variables. But how do I add coupon code in that?

Comment: Is your question how to add the coupon code (text) to the email template or how to make when the customer click on the coupon code it will automatically apply the discout to their cart?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `\app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\controllers\SubscriberController.php`.

```
public function newAction()
```

edit the email action and generate a new coupon code programmatic by using this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/178767/

It not the easiest method but it should work.